# Pixel font resources in byte format

Tags: display

To write text on a dot-matrix or LC display with an Arduino you need to have a pixel font in byte format (i.e. typically 1 bit = 1 pixel). 
On the Internet I have found surprisingly few resources for this.

Most of the results when searching for pixel fonts return true-type fonts (or similar) which are rather complicated to convert to obtain a satisfying result. 
Also, most of the fonts are rather high resolution.
Any good resources I have missed?

Comment: Try looking at lcd libraries. Those have some fonts embedded in it. Or search for 5x7 fonts.

Comment: Mainly I am wondering if there is a site collecting a few pixel fonts to choose from, which would be quite useful. (I found a few fonts here and there, mostly in libraries. Unfortunately, all had only ASCII.)

Comment: What other characters do you need? Memory is limited, so it's a good idea to limit the amount of characters.

Comment: Umlaute :) 4321

Comment: Just an umlaut, or letters with umlaut? If the latter you need some additional pixels (height). You can't make an `ä` with only 5x7 pixels.

Comment: Well, actually I'd even prefer 8 pixel height.

Answer (score 1):

The [UTFT library](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=51) has a SmallFont which is 8x12. Not sure whether this is too big for you, but it could be worth looking into. It is ASCII only, so you might want to add some characters yourself. But as someone mentioned, memory is limited, so add sparingly.

Comment: Moreover the creator of the library put online a tool to create new fonts starting from an image ([here](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/t_make_font_file.php)) and some other fonts made by other people ([here](http://www.rinkydinkelectronics.com/r_fonts.php))

Answer (score 0):

You could create the character data yourself. I've built a little script for a similar prospect a while ago that does translate a matrix of checkboxes to a bit-array: http://jsfiddle.net/qrsye920/

Answer (score 0):

Try the Dot [Factory](http://www.eran.io/the-dot-factory-an-lcd-font-and-image-generator/) and The LCD [Assistant](http://en.radzio.dxp.pl/bitmap_converter/). I'm happy with both. Let's you create any Windows font.